# URL encode part of a string in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, urlencode

I have a table containing a string column filled with URLs.

What I am looking to do is take everything after the domain name and URL encode it.

I have read a variety of articles which have quite elaborate and potentially time consuming ways of using extensions and building out functions. Is there a simple way to achieve this within a SELECT statement?

```
SELECT * FROM REPLACE('https://www.google.com/search?q=Stack+Overflow', 'https://www.google.com/', '')
```

In the example of: https://www.google.com/search?q=Stack+Overflow

I need to end up with: search%3Fq%3DStack+Overflow